# move camera with button in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity

I want to move Main Camera with button. Here's my gameplay: 
[image: gameplay]

Here's my scene:

[image: scene]

I want that when I click a button, main camera moves to right in another pic.

Comment: what have you tried to do ? What is your problem exactly ? This is not a place to beg for complete solutions but to find help with a problem you are facing.

Comment: @UriPopov , you are right, OP should show what he has done so far. But calm down bro :)

Comment: @HamzaHasan That was a perfectly calm statement about the nature of this site.

Comment: Although this is a very simple problem, it is not easy to answer, as you don't really provide any explanation of how you attempted to tackle this issue.  In order to get a good answer, you need to provide a good question.  As it stands now, your question is coming off as if you are asking for someone else to do this for you.  Please edit your question, and add more details on what you tried, and why it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Get the transform of the Camera and translate its position with the function
to be called on button click

```
public Transform cameraTransform;
public void TranslateCamera() {
  cameraTransform.transform.Translate (new Vector3 (20, 0, 0));
}
```

Like this